# MATLAB: Moving and Destroying Simultaneously plotted GUI Objects using Coordinates on axes through Push Buttons

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I wanted to create filled plots of geometrical shapes, which can be moved up and down by pushbuttons or keyboard hit. Firstly, the wont plot simultaneously so I have to use hold on for them. After pressing up, they do move up but their previous locations remained filled as well i.e they get copied, although I had turned hold off.P.S, I also want to destroy an object when touched by a certain object.How do we got about this?

Here is the piece of code:

```
global x
global y
global a 
global b

a = [ 7 8 9 8 ];
b = [ 2 1 2 3 ];
x= [ 1 3 3 1];
y = [ 1 1 3 3];

fill(x,y,[0.3 0.7 0.2]);

fill(a,b,[0.3 0.2 0.7])

axis([0,15,0,15])


% --- Executes on button press in up.
function up_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

hold off
global x
global y
global a
global b
y = y+2;
b=b+2;
hold on
fill(x,y,[0.3 0.7 0.2])
fill(a,b,[0.3 0.2 0.7])
hold off
axis([0,15,0,15])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use the return value of `fill()` to change the X/Y data.

```
function main

    close all;
    figure;
    hold on;

    objects(1) = struct('X',[ 7 8 9 8 ],'Y',[ 2 1 2 3 ],'fill_handle',[],'Color',[0.3 0.7 0.2]);
    objects(2) = struct('X',[ 1 3 3 1],'Y',[ 1 1 3 3],'fill_handle',[],'Color',[0.3 0.2 0.7]);
    objects(3) = struct('X',[ 1 5 3 1]+3,'Y',[ 1 2 3 3]+2,'fill_handle',[],'Color',[0.6 0.6 0.3]);

    for i=1:length(objects)
        objects(i).fill_handle = fill(objects(i).X,objects(i).Y,objects(i).Color);
    end

    axis([0,15,0,15])

    function keyPressCallback(~,eventdata)
        disp(eventdata.Key);
        dx = 0;
        dy = 0;
        if strcmp(eventdata.Key, 'rightarrow')
            dx = 1;
        elseif strcmp(eventdata.Key, 'leftarrow')
            dx = -1;
        elseif strcmp(eventdata.Key, 'uparrow')
            dy = 1;
        elseif strcmp(eventdata.Key, 'downarrow')
            dy = -1;
        elseif strcmp(eventdata.Key, 'delete')
            i=1;
            delete(objects(i).fill_handle);
            objects(i) = [];
        elseif strcmp(eventdata.Key, 'escape')
            close all;
            return;
        end

        for i=1:length(objects)
            objects(i).X = objects(i).X + dx;
            objects(i).Y = objects(i).Y + dy;
            set(objects(i).fill_handle, 'XData', objects(i).X);
            set(objects(i).fill_handle, 'YData', objects(i).Y);
        end

    end
    set(gcf,'WindowKeyPressFcn',@keyPressCallback);

end
```

Comment: Gracias! That works!
Any hint how to do the destroy part?

Comment: Right on spot. Only one thing not working is the movement through keyboard. Whenever I press up, it doesn't do anything or takes me to console which is displaying last command. Secondly , does fill command support editing of properties of fill? like border color, etc.

Comment: Not sure why moving with the arrowkeys doesnt work, it's fine here (R2015a, win64). You can edit the fill plot with `set()` and `get()`, read the docs for details: http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch-properties.html